# How to deduce the equation of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ to the curve?

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametric

Points $P(2p^2,\displaystyle\frac{1}{p})$ and $Q (2q^2,\displaystyle\frac{2}{q})$ lies on a curve.

Find the gradient of $PQ$ and also the equation of line $PQ$.

I’ve found the gradient of $PQ$ to be $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{2pq(p+q)}$

The equation of line $PQ$ is $2(p+q)pqy+x=2(p^2+pq+q^2)$

> Deduce the equation of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ to the curve. Hence, find the coordinates of the intersection point of tangent at $P$ and tangent at $Q.$

How do I deduce the equation of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ to the curve?

Comment: You can't, unless there is a typo and the curve is meant to be parametrized by $ ( 2x^2 , \frac{1}{x} )$.

Comment: @CalvinLin If the curve is indeed meant to be parametrised by $(2x^2,\frac{1}{x})$, how is the equation of tangents deduced?

Comment: Observe that $ X = 2 (\frac{1}{Y} ) ^2$. What is $ \frac{ d X } { d Y}$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{dX}{dY}=\frac{-4}{y^3}$? Is there any other way besides by differentiation?

Comment: It should be $Q(2q^2,\frac1{q}).$ Then the tangent is what you get when $p\to q$, i.e. $4q^3 y+x=6q^2$ and $q\to p$, i.e. $4p^3 y+x=6p^2.$